# Projection onto U through V

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be vector space and we have subspaces $U,V \subset X$ such $X = U \oplus V$. Then for each $x \in X$ there are unique vectors $x_U \in U$, $x_V \in V$ such $x = x_U + x_V$. A linear transformation $f \in L(X)$ is called a projection onto U through V if for each $x \in X$, we have, $f(x) = f(x_U + x_V) = x_U$.

1. In $\mathbb{R}^3$ determine a matrix of projection onto space $span(e_1, e_2)$ through line $span([1, 1, 1]^T)$
2. Assume that $f \in L(X)$ is projection onto $U$ through $V$. Prove that $im f = U$, $ker f = V$ and $f \circ f = f$
3. Assume that $f \in L(X)$ and $f \circ f = f$. Show that there are subspaces $U, V \subset X$ such $X = U \oplus V$ and $f$ is projection onto $U$ through $V$.

Can you help me with this task?

1. $e_1, e_2$ are ortogonal so I guess I should use ortogonal projection, right?

2., 3. I have no idea.

Comment: Can you add some of your own thought on the problem? Explain where you get stuck and we will help. We are however not a free homework site. You have to do some work too.

Comment: I added something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(2). For every $u \in U, 0 + u \in X$ and $f(0 + u)= u.$ So the map is surjective. To determine ker$f,$ use the fact that every element $x \in X$ can be written uniquely of the form $x_U + x_V,$ for some $x_U \in U, x_V \in V.$ This also shows that $f \circ f = f.$

(3). Take $U := Im(f), V:= Ker(f).$ Then $f \circ f = f$ will give that $U \cap V = \{ 0\}.$ Now show that $U + V = X.$

Answer (score 0):

for 1
try this :

for any $x \in \mathbb R^3 ;x=(c_1,c_2,c_3)=c_3(1,1,1)^t+(c_1-c_3)(1,0,0)^t+(c_2-c_3)(0,1,0)^t$

Define $T:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ by $T(x)=(c_1-c_3,c_2-c_3,0)^t$